# Using reflection to pass and modify a primitive without using array

Tags: reflection, kotlin

Working on a imgui [port](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui), I've been always used primitive arrays to simulate c++ pointers/addresses pass.

For example:

```
checkbox("Anti-aliased lines", bool.apply { set(0, style.antiAliasedLines) })
style.antiAliasedLines = bool[0]
```

where `bool: BooleanArray`

I just explored the possibility to directly pass the field instead, sort of c++:

`ImGui::Checkbox("Anti-aliased lines", &style.AntiAliasedLines);`

kotlin:

`checkbox("Anti-aliased lines", style::antiAliasedLines })`

I just needed to accomodate a corresponding `KMutableProperty0<Boolean>` on `checkbox()`, and I also double checked to have the possibility to set that field within the same function: there is a `get(): Boolean` and a `set(Boolean)`

My concerns are:

- does this play nice with java?
- are there any contraindications I should be aware of, if I go down this route? Such as performances or whatever?

Because I got the feeling that since this approach is somehow hacky and dirty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this play nice with java?

One thing that won't work is referencing synthetic properties that Kotlin uses to represent Java getters and setters, e.g. `getFoo` + `setFoo` → `foo` (and you cannot use a bound callable reference `bar::foo`). This is not supported for now.

You can try to workaround that by a custom `KMutableProperty0` implementation that accepts unbound callable references to `Bar::getFoo`, `Bar::setFoo` and `bar` and acts as a property reference in the sense of getting and setting its value.

> Are there any contraindications I should be aware of, if I go down this route? Such as performances or whatever?

A bound callable reference holds a reference to the receiver, so `style::antiAliasedLines` will keep `style` from GC, and you have to be careful about which callable references you store.