# Implementing a kotlin interface in java

Tags: java, reflection, reference, kotlin

So, after this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47176555/using-reflection-to-pass-and-modify-a-primitive-without-using-array) where I basically exploits reflection for passing primitive references to modify the primitive itself, like:

`_begin("Another Window", ::showAnotherWindow)`

I was looking for something to make something similar possible also from java, where at the moment I am using plains primitive arrays:

```
private boolean[] showAnotherWindow = {false};
imgui.begin("Another Window", showAnotherWindow);
```

@hotkey suggested me the possibility to create a class implementing the `KMutableProperty0` interface and that automatically gets and sets the corresponding variable

Example:

```
KMutableProperty0<Boolean> prop = 
  PropUtils.javaProp(this, t -> t.showAnotherWindow, (t, r) -> { t.showAnotherWindow = r; });
           
_begin("Another Window", prop);
```

So, I wanted to give it a try and implemented the following in java.

[Getter](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui/blob/master/src/test/java/imgui/Getter.java):

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Getter<T> {

    T get();
}
```

[Setter](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui/blob/master/src/test/java/imgui/Setter.java):

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Setter<T> {

    void set(T type);
}
```

And then the [class itself](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui/blob/master/src/test/java/imgui/JavaProp.java) (I just wrote the constructor, all the methods are those requested by the interface and automatically implemented by the IDE) :

```
public class JavaProp <T> implements KMutableProperty0<T> {

    private imgui.Getter<T> getter;
    private imgui.Setter<T> setter;

    public JavaProp(imgui.Getter<T> getter, imgui.Setter<T> setter) {
        this.getter = getter;
        this.setter = setter;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(T t) {
        setter.set(t);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Setter<T> getSetter() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
        return getter.get();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getDelegate() {
        return null;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Getter<T> getGetter() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T invoke() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLateinit() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConst() {
        return false;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<KParameter> getParameters() {
        return null;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public KType getReturnType() {
        return null;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<KTypeParameter> getTypeParameters() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T call(Object... objects) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public T callBy(Map<KParameter, ?> map) {
        return null;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public KVisibility getVisibility() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFinal() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOpen() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAbstract() {
        return false;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<Annotation> getAnnotations() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But whenever I try to run that, I get the following:

> Error:(45, 12) java: reference to Getter is ambiguous
>
> both interface kotlin.reflect.KProperty0.Getter in kotlin.reflect.KProperty0 and interface kotlin.reflect.KProperty.Getter in kotlin.reflect.KProperty match

The problematic function is this [one](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/imgui/blob/master/src/test/java/imgui/JavaProp.java#L43-L47):

```
  @NotNull
  @Override
  public Getter<T> getGetter() {
      return null;
  }
```

And the relevant file is `kotlin.reflect.KProperty.tk`, you can find it [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/builtins/src/kotlin/reflect/KProperty.kt)

Any idea how could I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify which interface you mean:

```
public KProperty0.Getter<T> getGetter()
```

But I would prefer to implement the class in Kotlin and only consume it from Java.

Comment: Nice idea, I wrote [this](https://gist.github.com/elect86/1cf30b62eac3839c998f4d58cffd3a17), any suggestion on how to implement the `TODO()` fields?